# Plotting points on an image and rendering on a different screen size in React Native

Tags: react-native

So I have an image of a field in which the user is able to plot points by touching their screen. These points are then stored within a database by obtaining the `e.nativeEvent.locationX`, `e.nativeEvent.locationY` on the user's press.

So when I plot the point on my Tablet and review where I placed the plot on the field image using my PC, It is displayed incorrectly. I assume this is due to different screen sizes and the image is a different size depending on the device screen size.

How do I resolve this issue so that the plots are consistent no matter what device you are using?

Any other possible solutions are much appreciated.

Below is how I display the image / obtain the user's x-axis and y-axis values and on press these values are retrieved by the function `ObtainPosition`

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.ObtainPosition}>
       <Image style = {{   
       width:wp('60%'),
       height:hp('100%'),
       resizeMode: 'contain'}} source={require('./pitch.png')}/> 
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

note - you may see wp and hp this is an import

```
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
```

Below is how I display user's plots (Note this is usually on a different screen/component). These plots are retrieved from the database and displayed in an array of objects. As you can see below the .map function loops through the array called `PlotsArray` and retrieves the x and y values and returns a View which is our plots.

```
<View>
                                                                    
      <Image style = {{   
         width:wp('60%'),
         height:hp('100%'),
         resizeMode: 'contain'}} source={require('./pitch.png')}/>
         {this.state.PlotsArray.map((data) => {
                return (
                      <View 
                      style={{
                               position: 'absolute',
                               left: data.x,
                               top: data.y,
                               backgroundColor:'#242424',
                               width: 10,
                               height: 10,
                               borderRadius: 50
                               }}>
                         </View> 

                               )
                         })}        
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `obtainPosition` function will need to take into account the Image element's left and right values (from the window / page) at the same time as you getting the actual x y coordinates of the click (if its padded, or the user is scrolled etc.)

You will also need to get the size of the image when you log the coordinates. So for example have a function similar to:

```
(event) => {
  var {height, url, width} = event.nativeEvent.source;
}
```

called within the onLoad prop of the image. That way when you store the x, y co-ordinates you can also record the size of the image at the time (say 200px x 200px). Later on, when you render the clicks overlaid on the image, you can asses the size of the image on the 'viewing' device and adjust x y coordinates accordingly or store them as percentages rather than fixed pixels.

Rough example here of how using % on top and left values can adjust  to the image varying in size https://jsfiddle.net/skfroxyt/ (have a play with editing the image height and width)

Comment: How do you suggest adjusting the x and y coordinates on the viewing device though? I feel that finding this out may solve my issue

Comment: I guess you should store it as percentages. So whenever it's set, you need to figure out the x,y coordinate *relative to the image* and then do these as a Top and Left percentage of the image height and width at the time.

later on, even if the image is say 500px x 500px, you will have the y co-ordinate as say 20% (0.2) and the X as 30% (0.3) and you can set a marker on the image based on 500 * 0.2 = Top: 100px and 500 * 0.3 = Left: 150px etc.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Could you demonstate with some code like related to mine? if not its absolutely fine you have give me a better understanding of my issue.

Comment: Hi, I have added a very quick example in my original answer.

If you edit the image width and height to be 900px wide or 900px tall etc, the plot point generally stays on the top of the middle house.

So in your App, so long as your containing `view` is the width of the image (i used display: inline-block to achieve it here with normal HTML) then using absolute positioning and % on top and left generally achieves what you need. Especially as you don't expect the image to vary THAT much over different devices.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Curious to know how you fixed this @Jim